# LARAVEL Selecting 2 tables at the same time

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have an animals table and images table.

Images has Id_animal.

The problem is that in AnimalController I am selecting the last 6 animals and I want to return their images at the same time.

I don't have any idea how to do it.

```
public static function getNewerAnimals()
{
    $animales = DB::table('animals')
    ->orderBy('date_found')
    ->limit(6)
    ->get();

    return $animales;
}
```

[image: Animals Table]

[image: Images Table]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use join for join two tables.

```
 $animales = DB::table('animals')
    ->orderBy('date_found')
    ->join('images','images.id_animal','animals.id')
    ->limit(6)
    ->get();
return view('viewname',compact('animales'))
```

**Edit**

In blade file

```
@foreach($animales as $animal)
    {{ $animal->nickname  }}
@endforeach
```

And if you want to use by relationship then it'll have `hasMany` relationship.

**Animal model**

```
class Animal extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'animals';
    public function images()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Image','id_animal','id')->where('type','interest');
    }
}
```

And in controller

```
$animales = Animal::with('images')
    ->orderBy('date_found')
    ->limit(6)
    ->get();
```

Comment: And how I can access the data from the view? Before I used {{$animal->nickname}}. Now I can't. And if I have more than one image, how can I select the second image for example? Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance. I did this  `$animales = DB::table('animals')
    ->orderBy('date_found')
    ->join('images','images.id_animal','animals.id')
    ->limit(6)
    ->get();
return compact('animales');`

Comment: It finally work! I am just dumb and I didn't had any data on the image table. Thanks!

Comment: @NikunjParadva Happy coding. glad it helped you :P